# Discrete vectors of repulsive and attractive force

Tags: electromagnetism

Consider simple example of two electric wires attracting and/or repelling one another. Can magnetic force vectors be reduced to smaller, discrete vectors, where there can be weak repulsion even if there is net attraction, and vice versa? For example, to the left, what schematic drawings show. To the right, actual vectors of attractive and repulsive force?

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused by your figure.  These look like field lines for the combined system rather than force exerted on a specific test objects.  The two may be related but I am not familiar with the ides expressed by your boxes.  That somehow the field lines in green (red) indicate attraction (repulsion).  Unless I have misunderstood something.

Comment: just standard for two wires either attracting or repelling, https://www.google.com/search?q=wire+repel+attract

Comment: the box to the right is an idea I thought of, have not heard it talked about, why I ask if the discrete vectors of magnetic force may look similar to what I draw there

Comment: But it isn't.  It is a field line map for the field from 2 sources.  Not the force between the two wires.

Comment: Vectors are always discrete! The lines are supposed to represent the flow of the field vectors, the fields are tangent vectors to those flow lines.

Comment: So, yes!  The discrete vectors would make the same curves as the lines you have (assuming they are correct).

Comment: yes vectors are always discrete, so discrete vectors of magnetic force to avoid misunderstanding

Comment: also yes its a field line map for field around both wires, that is self evident

Comment: So then what are you asking?

Comment: about vectors of repulsion and attraction, there is net attraction and net repulsion in both examples in image to the left, are there also weak opposite force, as shown in the image to the right

Comment: Not without a test object.

Comment: I think this is getting too long and needs to got to chat.  If you want to continue I will put it there.  Otherwise it seems to me that there is some confusion between field lines due to sources and forces acting on a test object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93695/discussion-between-ggcg-and-solon).

Comment: No confusion on field lines. no need to debate that and use space in this thread. There is clearly attractive and repulsive force. Merely asking if there are (weaker) vectors of opposite force, as shown in the image to the right